# Replace words in between slashes, but skip the first occurence

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have been playing around with [this online Regex tool](https://regexr.com/), but I don't make any progress.

I have multiple strings:

```
/a/b/c/
/x/z/
/y/
```

I am trying to replace the words in between the slashes with a `*`, but skip the first word, so that the output looks like this:

```
/a/*/*/
/x/*/
/y/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to negative lookahead for `^` at the beginning of the regex (`^` matches the beginning of the string, to ensure that the following match won't occur at the beginning), then match a `/` and word characters, then replace with `/*`:

```js
const repl = str => str.replace(/(?!^)\/\w+/g, '/*');
console.log(repl('/a/b/c/'));
console.log(repl('/x/z/'));
console.log(repl('/y/'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use `split()` and `.map()` instead of regex

```
var newStr = str.split('/').map(function(v, i){
  return i<=1 || v=='' ? v : '*';
}).join('/');
```

```js
function newStr(str){
  return str.split('/').map(function(v, i){
    return i<=1 || v=='' ? v : '*';
  }).join('/');
}
console.log(newStr('/a/b/c/'));
console.log(newStr('/x/z/'));
console.log(newStr('/y/'));
```